# CMake targets setup questions

Tags: cmake

Imagine the following situation:

I have "project" folder, in this folder I have "src" folder and 2 files "1.cpp" and "2.cpp".
Every single .cpp produce single executable. After cmake generate makefiles i want to be able to do the following :

- specify that i want to build executable "1", or "2" or both
- specify that i want to build all executables in debug mode
- specify that i want to build all executables in release mode
- specify that i want to build all executables in release and debug modes

so I want to be able to write the following:

- (c)make/anything 1
- (c)make/anything 2
- (c)make/anything all-release
- (c)make/anything all-debug
- (c)make/anything all-debug-and-release

What is the best way to achive this ? 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's unusual to specify that you want debug/release mode in the cmake files or when running make (maybe not true if cmake has generated a package/tarball/whatever - I've not needed that yet). Normally, you specify Release / Debug when you set up a particular build, by specifying `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` with `cmake-gui`. You can check the type of build to include/exclude items based on that in the cmake files using `if`. I don't do this, but I do use `if (CMAKE_HOST_WIN32)` to avoid building win32-specific code on Linux, and the principle is the same.

Comment: To build several configurations at once, I've always used the separate build trees and used a script to call make in each folder. I wouldn't call it a good way, but it gets the job done.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I will post another question about building several configuration at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a top-level CMakeLists.txt in the root which knows about your "src" directory (using `add_subdirectory`). Then in "src" you will need another CMakeLists.txt which specifies how to compile your executables. This in itself will make it possible to say, for instance:

```
make 1 2
```

As for the debug/release mode it can be specified in cmake via the variable `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`. But I usually, at top-level, instruct it for a debug or release mode if the variable is not specified:

```
IF( NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE )
  SET( CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug ) 
  SET( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -DDEBUG" )
ENDIF( NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE )
```

Another way of editing the build type without modifying the CMakeLists.txt is to do

```
make edit_cache
```

Which will bring up an ncurses dialog with the variables, `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` among them.